# Car gets stuck on waypoint

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have an automatic rigidbody car that is supposed to follow a set of waypoints on a mesh collider map but will get caught on any random waypoint and will rotate about that waypoint. Here is my code for the automatic car:

```
public class FollowThePath : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform[] target;
    public float speed;
    public float damping = 6.0f;
    public GameObject centerOfMass;
    private int current;

    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().centerOfMass = centerOfMass.transform.localPosition;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position != target[current].position)
        {
            Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target[current].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(pos);
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target[current].position - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
        }
        else current = (current + 1) % target.Length;
    }
}
```

I increased the mass, added a center of mass, froze the y axis position and rotation, lowered the center of mass. I noticed that the car gets stuck particularly, but not limited to curves. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two `Vector3`s for equality is generally a bad idea when handling moving objects.

Firstly because they use `float` internally, which always run the risk of being imprecise.

Secondly because Unity knows this and approximates the equality of two vectors internally. The problem is, that you don't have control over the precision being used by unity. When you implement it yourself like the function below it should be easier for you to figure out if that's the problem.

What's most likely the case is, that `if (transform.position != target[current].position)` never evaluates to `false`, since `transform.position` is (0,0,0) and  `target[current].position` is (0.00000000001,0,0) or something. They are **almost** equal, but not **quite equal**, at least using the `==` operator. Then your code in `else` is never executed.

You can try something like this, where `allowedDifference` should be in the scope of 0.0001 for ~0.1m precision, or 0.00000001 for ~0.1mm precision:

```cs
 public bool ApproximatelyEquals(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float allowedDifference = 0.00000001f){
     return Vector3.SqrMagnitude(a - b) < allowedDifference;
 }
```

//Edit:

To clarify, use it like:

```cs
if(!ApproximatelyEquals(transform.position, target[current].position), 0.00000001f)
```